# How to convert a 4 rows dataframe to 2*2 matrix in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, datamatrix

I have a data frame like this:

```
name  number
A     287        
B     1390       
C     1595       
D     369
```

I want to get a numeric data matrix like this:

```
287  369
1390 1595
```

with this sequence:

```
A  D
B  C
```

which means that A and B are on the left column and D and C are on the right column. The sequence is important.
How can I only make the numeric matrix with the sequence that I want? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can `sort` the 'number' column and create the matrix with `matrix`

```
matrix(sort(df1$number), 2, 2,byrow = TRUE)
```

-output

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  287  369
[2,] 1390 1595
```

---

Or if it needs to be based on the 'name' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(grp = 1 + !name %in% c("A", "D"), rn = rowid(grp), 
       name = NULL) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = number) %>% 
   select(-grp) %>%
   as.matrix
```

-output

```
        1    2
[1,]  287  369
[2,] 1390 1595
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), number = c(287L, 
1390L, 1595L, 369L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is also an option.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(name %in% c('A', 'B')) %>%
  bind_cols(filter(df, name %in% c('C', 'D'))) %>%
  select(where(~is.integer(.))) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  unname()

#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  287 1595
# [2,] 1390  369
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), number = c(287L, 
1390L, 1595L, 369L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```